# How to use the index of an array in another array?

Tags: java, arrays, function

I have a problem with my code, as far as I know, I could use the index of an array for another array of the same size, but different type. But this one only let's me work with the first's one type.

The objective is : If in an array there is an occupied slot, it's index will move to another array, which will mark with an X the occupied place.(The first one uses int, and the second, char.)

Thank you for your help.

```
public static char consolaej(int[][] ejcedula, char[][] matrixej){
  for (int i=0; i<ejcedula.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
        if(ejcedula[i][j]!=0){
            matrixej[i][j]=x;
        }
    }

 }
 return matrixej;   
}
```

Comment: I need to print in console a map of occupied sits, it's just a char I use for aesthetics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace `matrixej[i][j]=x;` with `matrixej[i][j]='x';`. Also, return type of function should be `char[][]` and not just `char`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int[][] ejcedula = {{1,0,1,2},{0,0,1,2},{2,3,4,0}};
    char[][] matrixej = new char[ejcedula.length][4];
    matrixej = consolaej(ejcedula,matrixej);

    /* Print Matrixej */
    for (int i = 0; i < ejcedula.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            System.out.print(" " + matrixej[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static char[][] consolaej(int[][] ejcedula, char[][] matrixej) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ejcedula.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if(ejcedula[i][j] != 0) {
                matrixej[i][j] = 'x';
            }
        }
    }
    return matrixej;   
}
```

Output:

```
 x  x x
   x x
 x x x
```

Comment: @Mylane Your Welcome! Please accept the answer by clicking the tick mark just below the voting counter if it solved your doubt.